# Mixing Conditional 1 and 2

Tags: meaning-in-context, conditionals, modal-verbs, descriptive-grammar, conditional-future

Are the following sentence ok to use ? 
Are they related to the mixed conditions where you mix between conditional 1 and 2 ????

1-I want to travel abroad and complete my study if I could.

2- I want to travel abroad and complete my study if I managed to.

Comment: What do you want thus "mixed conditional" to mean?

Comment: Not okay to me; should be *if I can, if I manage to* because these are not past events